# Issue getting information from database into variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

ok, so i have got a dropdownlist, which contains a number from a database(the amount of seats taken). If the rest of the dropdownboxes change(the flight arrival/departure), the dropdown box with the seats taken box changes to the correct piece of data associated with that flight
I am trying to store the seats taken into a variable, however, the number which is stored is the number from the previous value that was in the dropdown box and not the updated value

Is there a way i can get the new updated number into the variable?

Sorry for not being clear  :/

```
    int flightsTaken;
    string departure, arrival;

    departure = Convert.ToString(DropDownListDepartures.Text);
    arrival = Convert.ToString(DropDownListArrivals.Text);

    //Sets up how many flights are availabe for each departure place
    if (departure == "London (Ltn)")
        flightsAvailable = 12;
    else if (departure == "Edinburgh")
        flightsAvailable = 3;
    else if (departure == "Manchester")
        flightsAvailable = 6;


    flightsTaken = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList2.Text);  //THIS GETS THE PREVIOUS NUMBER NOT THE CURRENT NUMBER
    flightsAvailable -= flightsTaken;
```

Comment: Can you post some code please?

Comment: Easiest thing to do is turn post back on for the select lists, and rebind the whole group each page load based on the state changes from the post.

Comment: @asawyer I have enabled auto post back and no luck

Answer (score 1):

Where are you assigning the value of this dropdown box? It would need to be done on pageload OR any dropdownbox_change event. A postback will only run the page_load and the event fired.

The best option is to tie the update to the drowdown_change event to update the values of any other dropdown boxes that rely on it's value.

Comment: it is done via an sql command. The drop down list its self only contains one value  :/